# Amplifying multiples of four

Tags: java, arrays

The problem is to take an integer and return an array from 1 to the given number, where:

1. If the number can be divided evenly by 4, amplify it by 10 (i.e. return 10 times the number).
2. If the number cannot be divided evenly by 4, simply return the number.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    int num = 10;

    int[] arr = new int[num];

    for(int i = 1; i < num; i++){
        if((i)%4 == 0)
            arr[i] = (i)*10;
        else
            arr[i] = i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

I'm getting a pop-up error of "Wrong answer". Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If I understand right, instead of 'if ((i)%4 == 0)' use 'if ((arr[i] % 4) == 0)'

Comment: if you run your code it can't give "Wrong answer". How do you run your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your code lies in the first `for` loop. You're supposed to return an array from 1 to n but starting from index 1 will not do that. It'll leave the first index as 0 (default value). So, start at index 0 and while checking the conditions and entering the values, use `i+1`.

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {
    int num = 5;

    int[] arr = new int[num];

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        if((i+1)%4 == 0)
            arr[i] = (i+1)*10;
        else
            arr[i] = i+1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative implementation which is in my opinion more easy to read and shows more clearly what the function is actually doing. Just putting it out there for you to learn from so you can see alternative styles of approaching the same problem.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class Foo {
    private List<Integer> createList(Integer endValue) {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, endValue)
                .boxed()
                .map(value -> value % 4 == 0 ? value * 10 : value)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Integer> intList = createList(10);

        List<Integer> expectedList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 40, 5, 6, 7, 80, 9, 10);

        assertEquals(expectedList, intList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative answer! But I'm a novice in Java so I don't understand much of this code here except the fact that you're using a List. Can you kindly mention some resources where I can understand these new concepts?

Comment: @vagaBond I always really like the tutorials at baeldung.com. Here you can find a good overview of tutorials they offer on this subject: https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams. The "Stream Basics" tutorials are probably a good place to get started. Good luck in your studies!